# How to copy a local Git branch to a remote repo

Tags: git, version-control, distributed

I've taken the following steps so far:

1. Cloned a remote Git repo
2. Branched the master branch to an experimental
3. edited/tested/committed code in the experimental branch

Now, I'm not ready to merge experimental into master. I do however want to push it back to the remote repo as that's the repository I share with a few colleagues. I'd like for them to see what I've done in the experimental branch. I typically just access the remote repo via SSH.

How do I share my local branch on the remote repo, without affecting the remote repo's master branch?

Comment: This link is also very useful in this aspect.
[Sharing git branches](http://allmybrain.com/2008/09/15/sharing-git-branches/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make an existing git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

According to [git push manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

```
 git push origin experimental
```

Find a ref that matches `experimental` in the source repository (most likely, it would find `refs/heads/experimental`), and update the same ref (e.g. `refs/heads/experimental`) in origin repository with it.
**If `experimental` did not exist remotely, it would be created**.

This is the same as:

```
git push origin experimental:refs/heads/experimental
```

Create the branch `experimental` in the origin repository by copying the current `experimental` branch.
This form is **only needed to create a new branch or tag in the remote repository when the local name and the remote name are different**; otherwise, the ref name on its own will work.

Or, like mentioned in [git tip](http://reinh.com/blog/2008/04/18/git-push-just-the-tip.html), you can set up a "Branch’s Default Remote":

> You can use git config to assign a default remote to a given branch. This default remote will be used to push that branch unless otherwise specified.
>
> This is already done for you when you use git clone, allowing you to use git push without any arguments to push the local master branch to update the origin repository’s master branch.
>
> ```
> git config branch.<name>.remote <remote>
> ```
>
> can be used to specify this manually.

---

[Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458170/jan) suggests (for [git >= 1.7.0](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.7.0.txt)) the `push -u` (or `push --set-upstream`) option:

> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1) and other commands.

That way, you don't have to do any git config.

```
git push -u origin experimental
```

Comment: You should use the `-u` option for `push` to ensure that your local branch tracks the remote one after making it public.  
If you forget to use the `-u` option, you can just type `git push -u` afterwards in the branch, then `git pull` will work.

Comment: I have noticted that when you do this `git push origin experimental`, there is no evidence of any packs being uploaded. It looks like *the remote already has all the material from your earlier push; it just has to be hooked in to the refs*.

Comment: @Kaz: it would have all the material if those new commits were already pushed in another branch on remote. In that case, `git push origin experimental` would just create the branch `experimental` on the remote.

Answer (score 15):

If the name of your branch is `experimental`, and the name of the remote is `origin`, then it's

```
git push origin experimental
```

Comment: Same comment as above, but does that create the experimental branch implicitly on the remote repo, or will it push to remote's master?

Comment: it pushes the experimental branch and doesn't touch master on either the local side or remotely

Answer (score 1):

`git push -u <remote-name> <branch-name>` doesn't work if the newly created branch isn't spawned from the same repo, i.e. if you haven't created the new branch using `git checkout -b new_branch`, then this will not work.

For eg, I had cloned two different repositories locally and I had to copy repo2/branch1 to  repo1/ and then push it too.

[This](http://cmdlinelinux.blogspot.com/2014/02/git-push-new-local-branch-cloned-from.html) link helped me push my local branch (cloned from another repo) to my remote repo:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the authoritative github page for github remote management http://github.com/guides/push-a-branch-to-github.  It will help you answer all of your questions.

Comment: Doesn't that move it to the master branch, or will it implicitly create a origin/same_branch_name_as_local?

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin your_new_branch
```

### more info

after you have made few commits into your:

```
$ git checkout -b your_new_branch
$ git add file
$ git commit -m "changed file"
```

you push your branch specifying an upstream into one of the remotes repositories like following:

```
$ git push --set-upstream REMOTE YOUR_BRANCH
```

remotes can be seen by

```
$ git remote -v
```

usually, you will have single default remote `origin`. so you command would look like:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin your_new_branch
```

and all consequent pushes can be made just with `git push`.